# Facing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter.toOracleStringWithReplacement Exception

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, amazon-eks, spring-mybatis

Seeing below exception while running my application in eks(In my local its able to connects to oracle and persists the data base).

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter.toOracleStringWithReplacement([CI[BI[I)[B
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.mycompany.Main.main(Main.java:34)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter.toOracleStringWithReplacement([CI[BI[I)[B
    at oracle.sql.converter.I18CharacterConvertersWrapper.toOracleStringWithReplacement(I18CharacterConvertersWrapper.java:107)
    at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.convertWithReplacement(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:773)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:744)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:712)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.javaCharsToCHARBytes(PhysicalConnection.java:6021)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.StringBinder.bind(OraclePreparedStatement.java:18826)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3243)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2661)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3772)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3887)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:367)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:194)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:47)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:287)
    at com.mycompany.dao.DaoImpl.update(DaoImpl.java:55)
    at com.mycompany.Service.insertOrUpdate(Service.java:146)
    at com.mycompany.Service.lambda$insertUpdateOracle$1(Service.java:134)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at com.mycompany.Service.insertUpdateOracle(Service.java:131)
    at com.mycompany.Service.lambda$update$0(Service.java:37)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at com.mycompany.Service.update(Service.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1854)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 12 common frames omitted.
```

One Strange thing is I cant even see oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter in my local.

I am using ojdbc8:12.2.0.1.
Can somebody tell the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar issue with error `oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(int)` and found out a link to [oracle documentation](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/465177_1.html).

`One Strange thing is I cant even see oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter in my local.` Maybe some dependencies are using the method in question.

**The solution:** I found that I upgraded ojdbc14.jar to ojdbc7.jar so I downgraded it again to ojdbc14.jar and it worked. Hope this help. You might also want to have a look at [this doc](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason in my case was because there was an incompatible version of orai18n.jar its version was 11.2.0.4.0, while I was using ojdbc8.jar Implementation-Version: 12.2.0.1.0 and the database version was 19c

As Karan pointed out, that class: `oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverter` isn't in the ojdbc jar itself, instead it is in one of the dependent jars -> orai18n.jar

So the solution is to use a compatible version of this jar orai18n.jar

Answer (score 0):

In my case database was shutdown unexpectedly. I restarted oracle and everything start working well